# Runtime error for large inputs for sorting ( quicksort)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, runtime-error, quicksort, mergesort

This is a very simple program where the user inputs (x,y) coordinates and distance 'd' and the program has to find out the number of unrepeated coordinates from (x,y) to (x+d,y).

For eg: if input for one test case is: `4,9,2` then the unrepeated coordinates are (4,9),(5,9) and (6,9)(x=4,y=9,d=2). I have used a sorting algorithm as mentioned in the question (to keep track of multiple occurrences) however the program shows runtime error for test cases beyond 30. Is there any mistake in the code or is it an issue with my compiler?

For a detailed explanation of question: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/merge-sort/practice-problems/algorithm/missing-soldiers-december-easy-easy/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int partition(int *arr, int p, int r) {
    int x;
    x = arr[r];
    int tmp;
    int i = p - 1;
    for (int j = p; j <= r - 1; ++j) {
        if (arr[j] <= x) {
            i = i + 1;
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    tmp = arr[i + 1];
    arr[i + 1] = arr[r];
    arr[r] = tmp;

    return (i + 1);
}

void quicksort(int *arr, int p, int r) {
    int q;

    if (p < r) {
        q = partition(arr, p, r);
        quicksort(arr, p, q - 1);
        quicksort(arr, q + 1, r);
    }
}

int count(int A[],int ct) {
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ct; ++i) {
        if (A[i] != A[i + 1]) {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}

int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    long int tmp, y, d;
    int ct = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int x[1000];
    int j = 0;
    for (int l = 0; l < t; ++l) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &tmp, &y, &d);
        ct = ct + d + 1; //this counts the total no of coordinates for each (x,y,d)
        for (int i = 0; i <= d; ++i) {
           x[j] = tmp + i;  //storing all possible  the x and x+d coordinates
           j++;
        } 
    }
    int cnt;
    int p = ct - 1;
    quicksort(x, 0, p); //quicksort sorting 

    for (int l = 0; l < ct; ++l) {
        printf("%d ", x[l]); //prints sorted array not necessary to question
    }
    cnt = count(x, ct);  //counts the number of non-repeated vertices 
    printf("%d\n", cnt);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I see no obvious mistakes. What's the exact run-time error you're getting, and what's the (smallest) input you use when you get that?

Comment: It is around 25 testcases, I am not sure whether it is an issue with the compiler itself or the code, but I do not see any outputs for testcases beyond 25.(screen is just blank)

Comment: Runtime error... could you provide the error identify the line it is thrown from?

Comment: Looks to me like ‘count()’ reaches 1 beyond the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the bounds of the array `int x[1000]` is not enough for the data given below.